# Does Jquery Automatically Check Every Element of An Array for is() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a div and there are many checkboxes inside of that div. I want to learn that if none of them checked or not. I have a code like that:

```
$("#profileAssistPopUp [type='checkbox']").is('checked')
```

This returns me is any of them true else not. Firstly I want to learn that is that code line true?

My second and main question is

```
$("#profileAssistPopUp [type='checkbox']")
```

returns an array. How it works to write `.is('checked')` for an array? `Does it automatically checks every element of it and does mean if any of them checked an array is checked or not`?

My last question is how can I write the not of that code as like:

```
$("#profileAssistPopUp [type='checkbox']").is('not:checked') //This is not working
```

**PS:** I didn't test it enough yet but I think it works sometimes and sometimes not?

Comment: Why you are using id 'profileAssistPopUp' for all the checkbox, i didn't understand. I would prefer name attribute or even a class. Then select using $('input[type=checkbox][name=profileAssistPopUp]')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the jQuery docs:

> Check the current matched set of elements against a selector and return true if **at least one** of these elements matches the selector.

Source - http://api.jquery.com/is/

Your function will return true if one or more checkbox is checked. If you need to make sure that they are all checked, you would need to loop through the matched elements using $.each and check against each element individually.

Also, the correct selector would be:

```
$("#profileAssistPopUp [type=checkbox]").is(':checked')
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```
$("#profileAssistPopUp [type='checkbox']").is(':checked')
```

now the third one use

```
$("#profileAssistPopUp [type='checkbox']").not(':checked')
```

And for the 2nd one : it filters the array using your selection.
You can see yourself, go to this link: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
and find is:

You can also use this

```
$("#profileAssistPopUp [type='checkbox']").not(':checked').length > 0
```

Comment: $("#profileAssistPopUp [type='checkbox']").is(':checked') works. It returns true or false but $("#profileAssistPopUp [type='checkbox']").not(':checked') returns an array of not checked elements. Also $("#profileAssistPopUp [type='checkbox']").is(':not(:checked)') always returns true for me?

Comment: Also I try $("#profileAssistPopUp [type='checkbox']").is('checked') and it gives false everytime even checked one of them or not.

Comment: you can use $('input[type=checkbox][name=profileAssistPopUp]').not(':checked').length to detect how may is not checked and the last one $("#profileAssistPopUp [type='checkbox']").is(':not(:checked)')  is wrong, so i removed it from my answer.

Comment: You are using is('checked') not is(':checked') , You are missing ':'